# Need help parsing a set of json objects with python

Tags: python, json, object

"I am trying to read this json file into sqlite- python has having trouble reading the file since it is not a true json format; it is a set of json objects in one file; please help with python code i could use to fix the file?"

```
{"result": "3/11", "student_id": 2, "lesson_title": "Sending Data with Fetch La"}
{"result": "6/11", "student_id": 2, "lesson_id": "10"}
{"result": "1 out of 2", "student_id": 2, "lesson_id": 1, "lesson_title": "Use Fetch"}
```

I have tried json_load(JSON_FILE), it reads the file but when it goes to second json string it throws error since there is no comma separating the two json objects. The code below works for 1 line of json object.

```
import json
import sqlite3

JSON_FILE = "test_runs.log"
DB_FILE = "data/.internal.db"

traffic=json.loads(open(JSON_FILE))
conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_FILE)

a = traffic["result"]
b = traffic["student_id"]
c = traffic["lesson_id"]
d = traffic["lesson_title"]


c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('create table results (result text, student_id int, lesson_id 
text, lesson_title text)')
c.execute('insert into results values (?,?,?,?)', data)

conn.commit()
c.close()
```

Comment: I would suggest reading the file, using a `with/ as` statement, then loop over the lines and for each line, call `json.loads()`.

Comment: Are the json objects strictly separated by newlines? You could load each one with `json.loads` after splitting on newline

Answer (score 0):

If each line is one object, then read the file line by line

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_FILE)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('create table results (result text, student_id int, lesson_id text, lesson_title text)')

with open(JSON_FILE) as f:
    for line in f:

        traffic=json.loads(line)

        a = traffic["result"]
        b = traffic["student_id"]
        lesson_id = traffic["lesson_id"]  # don't rename cursor variable 
        d = traffic["lesson_title"]

        c.execute('insert into results values (?,?,?,?)', data)

conn.commit()
c.close()
```

Comment: I just copied your code. What did you want it to be?